# How to convert Special Character 'β' to its unicode

Tags: java, utf-8, hex, decimal

I want to convert **'β'** to its uni-code **'U+03B2'** using code. But when i tried to convert it, I am getting **'63'** as its integer value which is the value of **'?'** character. 
It is not converting to its correct value. Is there any way to get the correct value of **'β'** i.e. decimal **'946'** , hex **'03B2'**.

I have tried:

```
   int code = 'β';
   byte[] b = { (byte)code };
   String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the value in various forms:

```
int code = 'β';
System.out.println(code);                                       // 946 as an int
System.out.println(Integer.toString(code));                     // 946 as a String
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(code));                  // 3b2
System.out.println(String.format("%04x", code));                // 03b2
System.out.println(String.format("%04x", code).toUpperCase());  // 03B2
```

(Edit: Having seen the other answers I now know that you can use the format string `"%04X"` to get the answer in upper case form directly.)

Comment: I am getting 63
3f
003f
003F
?
?
 as output

Comment: I can't explain that. I've just pasted the exact code I used, and I tested it.

Comment: Unicode 003F is a question mark. Perhaps for some reason the beta character is not being recognised, and being treated as `'?'`.

Answer (score 2):

If UTF-8 is not your platform default character encoding, you'll need to make sure that the source file is saved in UTF-8 encoding, and then specify the `-encoding UTF-8` option when compiling (or another character encoding that supports `β`).

Your code is wrong because you are taking a `char`, which is 16 bits, and chopping it in half, keeping only the lower 8 bits. Narrowing casts can destroy data; they are required to be written explicitly to make you think about what you are doing.

Your code is like this:

```
int code = 0x000003B2;
byte[] b = { 0xB2 };
```

The byte sequence 0xB2 isn't valid UTF-8, so it's decoded with the replacement character, `�` (U+FFFD) in the string `s`. If your output device isn't configured to display that character, it will be swapped with a different replacement character on output, `?`.

If you get the encoding correct in your editor and compiler, this should work:

```
int code = 'β';
System.out.printf("U+%04X%n", code);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "β";
int i = s.codePointAt(0);
System.out.printf("U+%04X", i);
```